# Linear regression with pglm: factor effect and country

Tags: r, regression, econometrics

For my thesis I try to run a linear regression on a gravity trade model. The goal is to analyze the influence of investments on exports between several country pairs over time. For this purpose I have created the following query in R:

```r
ds <- pglm(Export ~ GdpExporter + GdpImporter - Distance + 
    InvestmentSum, index = c('CountryPair', 'Year'), family = poisson, 
    data=MyData)
```

My sample basically looks the same. All country pairs are pooled in a single sample.

```r
Year CountryPair Export GdpExporter GdpImporter Distance InvestmentSum
```

My objective is to find if there is an influence of investments on export. The query returns a coefficient for investments. However I have difficulties to understand how I could run this analysis to receive an investment coefficient depending on each single country pair. I assumed that for that I would need to split up the sample by countries, however I was told by my supervisor to group them in one sample.

Can you tell me please if there is a possibility to obtain this coefficient depending on the country pair?

NB: The usage of the Poisson distribution has no particular reason, it was give to me as a requirement.